# django - annotate() instead of distinct()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am stuck in this issue:

I have two models:

Location and Rate.

each location has its rate, possibly multiple rates.

i want to get locations ordered by its rates, ascendingly.

obvouisly, `order_by` and `distinct()` dont work together:

```
locations = Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs).order_by('locations_rate__rate').distinct('id')
```

then i read the docs and came to `annotate()`. but i am not sure whether i have to use a function between annotate.

if i do this:

```
locations = Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs).annotate(rate=Count('locations_rate__rate')).order_by('rate')
```

but this counts the rates and orders by the sum. i want to get locations with its rates ordered by the value of those rates.

my model definitions are:

```
class Location(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  adres = models.TextField()

class Rate(models.Model):
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name='locations_rate')
  rate = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
  price_rate = models.IntegerField(max_length=2) #<--- added now
  datum = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True) #<--- added now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue is not how to make query in Django for the problem you described. It's that your problem is either incorrect or not property thought through. Let me explained with an example:

Suppose you have two `Location` objects, `l1` and `l2`. `l1` has two `Rate` objects related to it, `r1` and `r3`, such that `r1.rate = 1` and `r3.rate = 3`; And `l2` has one rate object related to it, `r2`, such that `r2.rate = 2`. Now what should be the order of your query's result `l1` followed `l2` or `l2` followed by `l1`?? As one of `l1`'s rate is less than `l2`'s rate and the other one is greater than `l2`'s rate.

Comment: i believe you making an confusion between two notion: objects and attributes

Comment: very nice approach. exactly this is my case: only i take the latest rate of a location. in this case, i want to have as result: ``l2``, ``l1`` with rates: 2, 3.

Comment: Well if you query `Location.objects.values('pk').annotate(Max('locations_rate__rate_date')).order_by('locations_rate__rate')`, Django will add `'location_rate__rate'` in group_by clause (as anything in order_by needs to be in groub_by). So you have to do the ordering in python. O if you want the ordering according to lowest rate of locations then query would be: `Location.objects.values('pk').annotate(Min('locations_rate__rate')).order_by('locations_rate__rate__min')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
# if you want to annotate by count of rates
locations = Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs) \
    .annotate(rate_count = Count('locations_rate')) \
    .order_by('rate_count')

# if you want to annotate on values of rate e.g. Sum
locations = Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs) \
    .annotate(rate_count = Sum('locations_rate')) \
    .order_by('rate_count')
```

Comment: this doesnot do what i want somehow: this counts all rates for a location and orders by the sum of rates. but i need to order by the value of rates

Comment: So you need SUM of rates rather than COUNT of rates right? Check my updated answer.

Comment: look: i retrieve all locations. i want to get also latest rate of each locations, but ordered by rate value.

Comment: i dont want to sum. this is my problem. is there any way of calling like this: ``annotate('locations_rate').order_by('locations_rate')`` ?

Answer (score 1):

annotate(*args, **kwargs),Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc) that have
been computed over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet.

So if you want only to get locations ordered by its rates, ascendingly you dont have to use annotate()

```
     you can try this :

     loc = Location.objects.all()
     rate = Rate.objects.filter(loc=rate__location).order_by('-rate')
```

Comment: You have a bug `loc.id=location` should be `location__id=loc[0].id`

Comment: this up of where you are using it , within django shell or in the views. i have a rating models like this and it works fine, and i implement the same thing with django Model.Manager() perfect.

Comment: then i have to render two things: loc and rate to template. my wish is to get locations with their rates ordered by rates and with distinct ids. in this case i render only locations and this is easier to handle in tempplate.

Comment: it up to the tags you gonna use in the location template. for example you can said {% for my_loc in  rate%} {{my_loc.rate}} {% endfor %}

Comment: i hope you know how to write the tags in the template

Comment: of course, it's only up to how do you want to get things on the template.

Comment: i want it to be distinct. this is the reason why i cannot use order_by and why i asked this question. in your case, it is not distinct

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you want something like this:

```
locations = (Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs)
             .values('locations_rate__rate')
             .annotate(Count('locations_rate__rate'))
             .order_by('locations_rate__rate'))
```

You need the `Count()` since you actually need a `GROUP BY` query, and `GROUP BY` only works with aggregate functions like `COUNT` or `SUM`.

Anyway I think your problem can be solved with normal `distinct()`:

```
locations = (Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs)
             .order_by('locations_rate__rate')
             .distinct('locations_rate__rate'))
```

Why would you want to use `annotate()` instead?

I haven't tested both but hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer a bit to give more insight.

Comment: thanks. i dont really want to use annotate(), i just came across to this while reading docs. because order_by and distinct() wont work together as i am asking for field of another related table. but let me try this

Comment: Ah right only on PostgreSQL you can specify the distinct field (I'm using mostly Postgres). And in that case you have to use `order_by()` with `distinct()`. Make sure to read the note: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct